# Using non-laravel and composer package with Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, namespaces, package, composer-php, laravel-5.4

I was trying to make the api of [paymentwall](https://github.com/paymentwall/paymentwall-php) work on laravel 5.4 but I couldn't set it up.

I have it added directly to the root folder [folder structure](https://www.screencast.com/t/qwv8ZjuxLWc) sense there documentation says it needs to be added to the application I'm building. I have also tried to setup my root composer.json like this :

```
 "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Paymentwall\\": "paymentwall-php-master/paymentwall-php-master/lib"
    }
},
```

After **dumpauto** I called itlike t

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

use Paymentwall;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class CheckoutController extends Controller
{

```
public static function checkout(){
    return view('rent.checkout.checkout');
}

public function paymentDrive(request $request){


    Paymentwall_Config::getInstance()->set(array(
        'private_key' => 'xxxxxxxx'
    ));

    echo print_r($_POST, true);

    $cardInfo = array(
        'email' =>'iwds.rheman@gmail.com',
        'amount' => 10,
        'currency' => 'USD',
        'token' => $_POST['brick_token'],
        'fingerprint' => $_POST['brick_fingerprint'],
        'description' => 'Order #123'
    );

    $charge = new Paymentwall_Charge();
    $charge->create($cardInfo);
    $response = $charge->getPublicData();
    if ($charge->isSuccessful()) {
        if ($charge->isCaptured()) {
            // deliver s product
        } elseif ($charge->isUnderReview()) {
            // decide on risk charge
        }
    } else {
        $errors = json_decode($response, true);
    }
    echo $response;
}
```

}

But I'm still getting this error `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Paymentwall_Config' not found`

I really wanted to understand how this is done. **BTW** this api package uses different folder structures which makes me confuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run:

```
composer require paymentwall/paymentwall-php
```

in your console and that should be everything (you don't have to manually copy package file).

You shouldn't need to update your `composer.json` manually for this. This library is available on packagist here: https://packagist.org/packages/paymentwall/paymentwall-php

Comment: This does fixed the problem with paymentwall thanks. But still I am confuse on how to implement a none composer package.